# C++ piping issue

Tags: c++, pipe, fork

I am trying to to fork my c++ program and direct the parents output into the childs input, I am using pipe() and fork(). In the directory of the program there is a file called input.txt. Unfortunately the only output I get is "wc: stdin: read: Bad file descriptor". Does anyone know why this is? If so what am I doing wrong? Thanks

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <iostream>
#include<sys/types.h>
#include<sys/stat.h>
#include<fcntl.h>
#include<stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]){

        int pipes[2],pid,stdIn,stdOut;

        stdIn = dup(0);
        stdOut = dup(1);

        pipe(pipes);

        pid = fork();

        if(pid == 0){
                dup2(pipes[1],0);
                close(pipes[1]);
                execlp("wc","wc",NULL);
        }
        else{
                dup2(pipes[0],1);
                close(pipes[0]);
                std::cout<<"input.txt"<<std::endl;
                dup2(stdOut,0);
                std::cout<<"parent done\n";
                wait(NULL);
        }

        std::cout<<"after"<<std::endl;
        return 0;
 }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several things that should be fixed in your program:

1. Use `STDIN_FILENO` and `STDOUT_FILENO` instead of 0 and 1. This values may change on different platforms and you have also made a mistake which could probably be avoided if you've used names instead of value, e.g.               `dup2(stdOut,0);` duplicated `stdin` and you need to duplicate `stdout` here.
2. You should **close write end of the pipe in both child and parent**.
3. By making `wc` read from `stdin`, you are then passing "input.txt" string to it - it will return stats for that string, not for the file. You could either fix it be opening a file descriptor for that file or using `exec*` with `cat`.
4. None of your calls the functions like `pipe()` or `execlp()` checks for failure. You should do it like that:

   ```
   if (pipe(pipes) == -1) {
       perror("pipe");
       exit(1);
   }
   ```
5. You don't need `stdIn` variable.

You will find fixed code below (it does not implement what I've described in the (5) though):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    int pipes[2], pid, stdOut;

    stdOut = dup(STDOUT_FILENO);

    pipe(pipes);

    pid = fork();

    if (pid == 0) {
        dup2(pipes[0], STDIN_FILENO);
        /* You need to close write end of the pipe here */
        close(pipes[1]);
        execlp("wc", "wc", NULL);
    } else {
        std::cout << "Parent setup" << std::endl;
        dup2(pipes[1], STDOUT_FILENO);
        /* You need to close write end of the pipe here as well */
        close(pipes[1]); 
        /* This will only send the string "input.txt" through the pipe, to the
         * wc command */
        std::cout << "input.txt" << std::endl;
        dup2(stdOut, STDOUT_FILENO);
        std::cout << "Parent done" << std::endl;
        wait(NULL);
    }

    std::cout << "Program finished" << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

**EDIT:** As suggested in the comment to the other answer, you could simple use `xargs wc` to read stdint as file argument:

```
execlp("xargs", "xargs","wc",NULL);
```

Answer (score 0):

You have the pipe backwards, you have connected the write end of the pipe to the standard input of `wc`. You will need to close the write end of the pipe in both processes before `wc` will detect an end of file condition and terminate normally.

You also incorrectly restore the original standard output to the standard input of the parent.

Furthermore `wc` will by default not interpret standard input as a list filenames and will therefore not read `input.txt`.

Comment: With regard to `wc` not processing standard input, @mathJohn could invoke `xargs wc` instead.